# Importing COM PIA when hosting PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a COM component and its PIA installed in the GAC.  In PowerShell, I can do

```
$a = New-Object -com MySvr.ProgId
$x = $a.Method([MySvrLib.MyEnum]::enumValue)
```

and it understands the COM enum type.

But when I host PowerShell in my app using a RunSpace, provide my component instance via `RunSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable` and Invoke this code:

```
$x = $a.Method([MySvrLib.MyEnum]::enumValue)
```

I get "Unable to find type [MySvrLib.MyEnum]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded."

Is there a way to load the type definitions of my component into the hosted PowerShell instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `RunspaceConfiguration` (option to configuring a new Runspace), there is an `Assemblies` property in which you can add an AssemblyConfigurationEntry object that points to your PIA.  Note: the constructor for the AssemblyConfigurationEntry expects an assembly qualified name like `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c`.

Comment: Thanks.  After creating the RunSpace, I tried rs.RunspaceConfiguration.Assemblies.Append(new AssemblyConfigurationEntry("MySvr", @"C:\Path\To\MySvrPIA.dll")), and I got "Could not load file or assembly 'MySvr' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest." when opening the RunSpace.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the name of a GAC'd PIA you have to provide the assembly qualified name e.g. something like `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c`